# jQuery UI resizable: elem is undefined error in jQuery's acceptData function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-resizable

I'm using jQuery UI Resizable to resize a div. I'm getting "elem is undefined" error in console and I can't figure out what is wrong.

I've tried different jQuery versions.

You can see my app at:
[http://klip.dev.xhtml.si](http://klip.dev.xhtml.si/)
The arrows in the middle of content is the handler for resizable.

Comment: [http://klip.dev.xhtml.si](http://klip.dev.xhtml.si)

Comment: Strange that if I tried only the resizeable() code (at the end of init.js) and included only the #content's .left and .right, the resizeable() did not throw any error, perhaps it's somewhere in your code. Please paste only the affected js code, html, and/or css and not the whole website.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem.

I updated JQuery, so it checks if the element is undefined:

```
    acceptData: function( elem ) {
    /* Add this line to the code */
    if(elem === undefined) return false;
```

And by the way, I am using jQuery v1.8.3